# Laravel expire csrf token or page after form submission

Tags: php, forms, laravel, csrf

My application has two forms to submit input to perform some transactions and calculation, I want to avoid from re-submission, how can I avoid that?

For e.g. if user tries to push history back button, he should not see the previous form instead should see page expire or auto redirection to 1st form.

Or how can I set page expiration in Laravel?

As `csrf_token` expiration do it after timeout and force user to go to 1st page or login page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the helper of laravel. 
Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar'))
Form::close()

In this case laravel will make csrf token instead of you and you will easily avoid of resubmit cases.
Also you can yourself make csrf token with this code: Form::token()

Comment: I was using csrf_field() method but I tried your method still I can go back and change the inputs. After 2nd form submission I am redirecting to a simple url but history.go(-1) letting me change inputs

Comment: You can put token to session and when client submits, compare the token with session, if true, delete session, else return to index